# How do I wire up my ceiling fan?

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

The junction box in the ceiling has three wires: black, white, and bare copper. The ceiling fan has four wires: black, white, blue, and green. I assume the blue goes to the light, but don't know where to connect the blue wire in the junction box.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your ceiling fan is controlled by a single wall switch, with fan speed and light being controlled by pull chains on the fan. Therefore, connect both the blue and black from the fan to the black in the ceiling box. Connect white to white, and green to bare copper (ground). The orange wire nuts that typically come with fans are appropriate for all connections.

If your fan doesn't have a light kit, or you decide not to install it, just put a single orange wire nut on the blue wire instead. You'd still connect black to black, white to white, and green to bare copper.

Answer (score 1):

If the ceing fan has a light, then you'll connect the blue wire to the black one coming into the the fixture. If there isn't a light on the the fan, you can just cap it off. Good luck!

Comment: (in addition to the black-black connection, not instead of)

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't mean istead of.  I'm new here and i'll be careful in the futer, how I word my answers. Thanks

Comment: that's ok, I understood you didn't mean instead of. My comment was just to clarify for OP, since the answer didn't specify what to do with the fan's black wire.